# DataFrame: выделить столбец/строку для поиска в нем min()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Дана матрица:

```
GIVEN_MATRIX = [[0., 10., 25., 25., 10.],
                [1., 0., 10., 15., 2.],
                [8., 9., 0., 20., 10.],
                [14., 10., 24., 0., 15.],
                [10., 8., 25., 27., 0.]]

df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
```

Как в цикле выделять столбец и строку для поиска в нем минимального значения?
Можно ли для этого использовать переменную цикла?

Вариант:

```
di = df.iloc[i].min(axis=1)
```

не работает.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь найти минимумы строк, исключив диагональные элементы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать циклы в Pandas нужно только в тех оч. редких случаях когда не существует более оптимального решения.

Это как купить спорткар и всегда использовать только первую передачу - просто потому, что вы не знаете как переключать скорости.

Если вопрос о том как найти минимумы строк или столбцов, исключив диагональные элементы, то это можно сделать так:

Исходный фрейм с именованными столбцами и строками (для наглядности):

```
In [17]: df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=list("abcde"), index=[f"row{i}" for i in range(1, 6)])

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
         a     b     c     d     e
row1   0.0  10.0  25.0  25.0  10.0
row2   1.0   0.0  10.0  15.0   2.0
row3   8.0   9.0   0.0  20.0  10.0
row4  14.0  10.0  24.0   0.0  15.0
row5  10.0   8.0  25.0  27.0   0.0
```

NOTE: если не исключать диагональные элементы то и для строк и для столбцов минимумами будут являться диагональные элементы.

---

**Решение:** сначала заполним главную диагональ бесконечно большим значением:

```
In [19]: np.fill_diagonal(df.values, np.inf)

In [20]: df
Out[20]:
         a     b     c     d     e
row1   inf  10.0  25.0  25.0  10.0
row2   1.0   inf  10.0  15.0   2.0
row3   8.0   9.0   inf  20.0  10.0
row4  14.0  10.0  24.0   inf  15.0
row5  10.0   8.0  25.0  27.0   inf
```

---

теперь можно использовать метод [DataFrame.min()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) для нахождения минимумов столбцов:

```
In [23]: df.min(axis=0)
Out[23]:
a     1.0
b     8.0
c    10.0
d    15.0
e     2.0
dtype: float64
```

параметр `axis` имеет значение `0` *по умолчанию*, поэтому его можно не указывать:

```
In [24]: df.min()
Out[24]:
a     1.0
b     8.0
c    10.0
d    15.0
e     2.0
dtype: float64
```

или для минимумов строк:

```
In [25]: df.min(axis=1)
Out[25]:
row1    10.0
row2     1.0
row3     8.0
row4    10.0
row5     8.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Уважаемый, MaxU! Вы правы, конечно в своем сравнении со спорткаром. Я решаю задачу TSP (Travel Salesman Problem). В алгоритме предусмотрен цикл по обработке данных матрицы - поиск всех нулеых элементов и последовательная оценка каждого из этих элементов для принятия решения. Отсюда и взялся цикл. Для поиска вектора всех нулевых элементов я использую метод np.find() - Numpy. Есть ли подобный метод в DataFrame, который выдает вектор индексов всех найденных по какому-то условию элементов? Спасибо за содержательные ответы!

Comment: @GreyKoshak, Что вы подразумеваете под `"вектор индексов всех найденных по какому-то условию элементов"`?  И в Numpy нет метода `np.find()` - выдаёт: `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'find'`.

Comment: @GreyKoshak, tсли у вас возник новый вопрос, то лучше оформить его в виде нового SO вопроса.

Comment: Ошибся, извините! result = np.where(df == 0)  # Найти все нулевые элементы, Так и сделаем - новый вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Можно без указания оси

```
di = df.iloc[i].min()
```

А если с осью, то смотрите, что получается

```
df.iloc[1]

0     1.0
1     0.0
2    10.0
3    15.0
4     2.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

поэтому ось надо ставить 0 - ось, вдоль которой будет работать агрегирование

```
df.iloc[1].min(axis=0)
```